# going to another xml from the main xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I m totally new to program and I m trying to make a simple app.
I need to jump from one xml to another xml by clicking a button, and I m stopped here.
I only know how to use graphical layout and how should I do it???

I want to jump from Activity_Main.xml to 2bb.xml, and 2bb.xml to 2result.xml and at last from 2result.xml back to Activity_Main.xml.

my A_M.xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="1"
tools:context="com.example.soo.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame,NewApi,UnusedAttribute" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="215dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="@string/B2"
    android:onClick="2bb" />
```

Comment: please go through this link and learn android http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Press ALT + Right Arrow to switch between open xmls

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, depends on what your looking for. 
You can call a new activity from your MainActivity and inflate 2bb.xml when the new activity is created, or you can use different fragments, and just transition between fragments in the same activity. I suggest going over some tutorials regarding [Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) and [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

To go to other xml, you have to create one activity for one xml and each button has to put action startactivity.